# Operator overloading strange results

Tags: c++

heres my class

```
class Vector
{
public:
    Vector();
    Vector(float x, float y, float z);

    float x;
    float y;
    float z;

    Vector &operator+(const Vector &other) const;
    Vector &operator+=(const Vector &other);
    Vector &operator*(float n) const;
};

//op overloading functions impl
Vector &Vector::operator+(const Vector &other) const
{
    Vector result = *this;
    result.x += other.x;
    result.y += other.y;
    result.z += other.z;
    return result;
}

Vector &Vector::operator+=(const Vector &other) 
{
    this->x += other.x;
    this->y += other.y;
    this->z += other.z;
    return *this;
}

Vector &Vector::operator*(float n) const
{
    Vector result = *this;
    result.x *= n;
    result.y *= n;
    result.z *= n;
    return result;
}
```

I am getting incorrect result when trying to use more complex equation. For example this WORKS:

```
Vector vChange = velocity * time;
position += vChange;
```

while this DOESNT:

```
position += velocity * time;
```

i.e. it compiles and runs but writes some bogus into position

Same for this one:

```
Vector& Reflect(const Vector& I, const Vector& N)
{
Vector v = I - 2 * Dot(N, I) * N;
}
```

Could you advise me what am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: I recommend reading the [operator overloading FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4421706/46642).

Answer (score 5):

You are returning a reference to a local variable in `operator*`. That's undefined behavior. Return by value instead:

```
Vector Vector::operator*(float n) const
{
    Vector result = *this;
    result.x *= n;
    result.y *= n;
    result.z *= n;
    return result;
}
```

Same for `operator+`.

Answer (score 2):

For your `operator*` and `operator+`, you have to return the `Vector` by value, not by reference. What you have there is returning a dangling reference, and that is undefined behaviour.

Comment: would i still return reference for +=?

Comment: @Mikhail: Yes, because you're returning `this` in that case, and not a local variable that's going out of scope.

Answer (score 1):

You're returning a reference to a local variable.  Don't do that.  Your non-assigning operators should return by value, not by reference.